# Editing a cell in Nat table

Tags: nattable

I have a Nat table with some data in it.I want to add a new row just after the selected cell.I was able to do it. Now I have to select the newly added cell(0,new rowPosition) and edit it too. Using the selectCellCommand I was able to select the cell but the problem is with editing the cell. when I try to get the cell from Nat table using the api getCellByPoition I get null. Now this happens when I have a scrollbar and few rows are hidden at the top.Selection layer works fine and selects the first cell of the newly added row but Nat table doesn't give me the cell for the same row position.How can I get the cell to edit it? I am firing the EditCellCommand for the specified rowposition and getting the cell editor from nat table using getActiveCellEditor method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not aware of the position-index transformations in NatTable. I suppose you try to access your object via index. But in scrolled state the position is not equal to the index.

Please read our getting started tutorial on this topic http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_layers